# How to crop Metafile

Tags: c#, vb.net, metafile

I'm working with MetaFile. Is there any way to crop a metafile to zoom a specific part?

I'm thinking of redrawing it on a larger bitmap then crop that image, but I know this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

When drawing to a `Graphics` surface, i.e. when drawing to a `Bitmap`, you can easily crop using one of the overloads of the `DrawImage()` method. Here is an example where only the lower right quarter of the metafile is drawn to the bitmap:

```
Metafile metafile = ...;

Bitmap target = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
    g.DrawImage(metafile, -1000, -1000, 2000, 2000);
    g.Flush();
}
```